# Hyperlink to aspx

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I am trying to create a hyperlink from an Office document to a aspx website with no success. I am not an expert at all in this field, and it would be extremely important to be able to do this.
I am using Windows and Internet Explorer because it is mandatory for the project I'm working in.

I will explain what I've done so far:

1) Right click in the specific location of the website and “create shortcut” (internet explorer). This way I can access the place I want to go by clicking on the created shortcut.

2) Copy the above working link to a hyperlink in any Office document. This way it brings me the main SW page, not the specific location I want.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-format-or-delete-a-hyperlink-0c2f680d-5f61-48b9-9f6f-894c6f3cab55

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have tried that before...